# My Ubuntu 12.04 installed DVD-RW recorder PATA as SCSI 

Tags: installation, cd-drive, sata, burning

Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit installed DVD-RW recorder PATA as SCSI. My DVD-RW recorder is in /dev/sr0 as SCSI. I opened Disk Management and my IDE PATA drive is installed as SCSI. I can't use this drive because it hangs computer (I need to press reset button on CPU to get back to Ubuntu).
What should i do to get the drive back to function correctly with the correct drive (IDE mode)?
Also With the first(default)  kernel version of the Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit , it was all functioning normally

Help me please.

Comment: Did you tried booting from old kernel. And does the problem still exists from old kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem removing the PATA DVD-RW Recorder and putting a SATA DVD-RW Recorder in my machine.

The IDE chipset of the my motherboard is VIA, and uses the pata_via module. I believe that this module is with some bug, because it register some devices as SCSI, and then they don't function properly.